# Trying to add XML file for layout-land on Android application

Tags: android

I want to add an XML file for layout-land. But when i go to New > Android XML file there is no Layout-land option. I try to add it manually by creating a new folder and an XML file inside it, but eclipse indicates an error. How can i add alternative XML file for layout-land on eclipse indigo?

Comment: What is the error? The folder must be called 'layout-land' and should be under the 'res' folder.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new XML file click NEXT, instead of FINISH; then, add the Orientation and select Landscape. The folder `Layout-land` will be created automatically with the new XML file within it.